# OData4j for Android: ClassNotFoundException for XmlInputFactory

Tags: java, android, odata

This is the first time I'm attempting to learn Java so I thought i'd port my Windows Phone application over to Android to begin learning. I'm trying to use the OData4j 0.7 jar library to call my existing WCF Data Service (which works in my WP app / browser), but I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myfirstapp.blazemonkey.com.myfirstapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/
07-26 13:02:41.452    3736-3736/myfirstapp.blazemonkey.com.myfirstapp E/ProviderFactory﹕ The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
...
```

every time I run this code:

```
ODataConsumer consumer = ODataJerseyConsumer.create(serviceUrl);
```

I've been pulling my hair out for a long time so hopefully someone can point me to the right direction! I have already added the users-permission tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

so that shouldn't be the problem either.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: What IDE do you use Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio. Also targeting SDK Version 20 if that helps.

Comment: Ok, I will implement a example using OData4j.

Comment: Please @gary, provide me more information of logcat.

Answer (score 1):

`javax.xml.stream` package is not a part of Android. You cannot use it or any other library requiring it in your Android app. That's why you're getting error.

According to OData4j description, it can work with StAX parser too, which is present in Android. You should have a look into their [official Android example](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/odata4j-android/?repo=android&r=cf0d71c05b6d3fab6cd5c7abc65d359e6cba9b13#odata4j-android%2Flibs) to find out how this library should be used with StAX parser in Android. Hope this helps.