# How to start odata4j and olingo odatav2 on android

Tags: java, android, xml, olingo, odata4j

I'm trying to work with `odatav2` on ANDROID.

I compile my android application with gradle:

```
compile files('src/lib/odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle.jar')
```

But at runtime I got:

> java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present

Can't find how to resolve this for a long time.
Please write here how to fix this without links for old deleted/unreadable pages/examples.

> (similar problem with olingo odatav2: XMLInputFactory exception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OData4j for Android: ClassNotFoundException for XmlInputFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973616/odata4j-for-android-classnotfoundexception-for-xmlinputfactory)

Comment: You may want to try the answer linked by meJustAndrew or reword your question if it's nothing like that question instead.

Comment: Where is no answer. I already see this before posting this question.

Comment: i got odatav2 lib for android by writing directly to apache olingo